SqlAlchemy Select with date condition
I Implemented following Query By SQLAlchemy in Python:
url = URL.create(
                 drivername="access+pyodbc",
                 query={
                 "odbc_connect": connStr,
                 },
                 )
with create_engine(url).connect() as con:
     sql_get_anag = text(f"SELECT Tipo_Presenza FROM Presenza WHERE ID_Anagrafica = {IDValue} AND Giorno > {current_day_insert} AND Giorno < {current_day_insert_1}")
     Presenza_tab =  pd.read_sql_query(sql_get_anag, con)

This return following error:
Exception has occurred: ProgrammingError
(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access] Errore di sintassi (operatore mancante) nell'espressione della query 'ID_Anagrafica = 4 AND Giorno > 24-05-24 00:00:00 AND Giorno < 25-05-24 00:00:00'. (-3100) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: SELECT Tipo_Presenza FROM Presenza WHERE ID_Anagrafica = 4 AND Giorno > 24-05-24 00:00:00 AND Giorno < 25-05-24 00:00:00]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access] Errore di sintassi (operatore mancante) nell'espressione della query 'ID_Anagrafica = 4 AND Giorno > 24-05-24 00:00:00 AND Giorno < 25-05-24 00:00:00'. (-3100) (SQLExecDirectW)")

In my opinion is the Date syntax for where condition that is not correct, but I don't know what is the correct syntax.
Have you suggestion about this problem?
Thank you
Mario
I tried to add and remove the ' on the date parameters but without success.
My expectation is to make the select query correctly
Thanks

Please stop using string formatting to create queries, this is open to SQL injection and is probably part of the issue here since you're not passing an actual datetime

first you could translate to English text from error message.

second: you could display SQL query - to see if it correct. And you could run it directly in database (eg. using DBeaver) to check if it works correctly.

you should check documentation for this database - maybe it needs only date Giorno > 24-05-24. Or maybe it has to be in " (instead of ') Giorno > "24-05-24 00:00:00". Or maybe it needs dots instead of - -  Giorno > "24.05.24". Or maybe you have to use full year because I don't know if it is 2024.05.24 or 24.05.2024 - and database may also has this problem

What datatype is your Giorno column expecting. Is it a datetime object or a string. If it is a datetime object, have you tried converting the date you are parsing to a python datetime object before parsing it in? Also please do listen to @roganjosh

Firstly, you should not be using string formatting/interpolation to pass parameters to a query. This is open to SQL injection which is a major issue. The usual counter-argument people give is "well I know where the data comes from" and think that somehow string formatting is easier. It is not, as you are finding. There is never a case in which it is easier than parameterization.
Second point, wrapping queries in dataframe libraries makes such things harder to debug. So, the first step is using SQL alone and then passing the data to pandas.
url = URL.create(
    drivername="access+pyodbc",
    query={"odbc_connect": connStr,}
)

with create_engine(url).connect() as conn:
    query = text("""
        SELECT 
            Tipo_Presenza 
        FROM 
            Presenza 
        WHERE 
            ID_Anagrafica = :id_value 
            AND Giorno > :current_day 
            AND Giorno < :current_day_1
        """
    )
    result = conn.execute(
        query, 
        {
            'id_value': IDValue,
            'current_day': current_day_insert,
            'current_day_1': current_day_insert_1
         }
    )
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=result.keys())

Separately, I don't think you really want to be using create_engine like this. You should create the engine once and then use with engine.connect() as conn to avoid the overhead of establishing an engine each time.

df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params={…}) should work, too.

@GordThompson indeed, though the point here was to separate them out. In general I actually don't like using dataframe wrappers for SQL execution as its methodology can be obscured (pandas used the slow executemany for psycopg2 for quite a while. To the best of my knowledge, pandas will still pull the results through a python layer. It's a different story for polars where the engine can go straight to Arrow format without the python interim step
